# Locate actual path of ContentAssets image under episerver media tab

Tags: episerver

Is there any way to traverse through the image file that belongs to content asset folder?
For Instance:
https://loca.abc.com/contentassets/90a388f260a04f54b4056becc1c58307/lorem-ipsum-alternatives.png

If I have to locate this file in episerver media tab, how can i achieve this?
It is easy to locate files under global assets & site assets from **"For all Site"** & **"For this site"** container under Media tab but I cannot locate the files that are uploaded as part of content assets folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

GUID in path (`90a388f260a04f54b4056becc1c58307`) means that this is (most probably) a "For this page" / "For this block" folder.

You can query database like this using that GUID:

```
SELECT pkID, ContentOwnerID FROM tblContent WHERE ContentGUID = '90a388f2-60a0-4f54-b405-6becc1c58307'
```

`pkID` will contain an ID of content folder, and `ContentOwnerID` will contain GUID of content (page or block) which is this folder belongs to, which you can use again to find owner content ID.

(you can also do the same in code using for example `IContentLoader.Get<T>(Guid contentGuid)`)

Then you can use that ID to change edit URL and open that content inside edit UI, and then click "For This Page" / "For This Block" folder in Media tab.

Comment: Basically,I need to locate these files in episerver edit mode.I am aware that the file is located in "For this page" but if these files are replaced or removed then there is no way to locate it within edit mode.It's strange that episerver doesnt store information for these kind of scenario.The problem with files in content asset folder is ,even if the files that are no longer used are still available in the system. I need to find a way to remove these files from episerver that are no longer referenced.

Comment: For that purpose you might want to use built in EpiServer scheduled job `Remove Abandoned BLOBs`

Comment: "Remove Abandoned BLOBs" scheduled job doesn't remove all abandoned blobs. It looks like that if there is no reference to the file in the DB, it does not remove the file. It removes only files which are not used and has a reference in the DB. I do not know why there are files without reference in the DB, but I assume that Episerver deletes the reference from the DB but fails to delete the file which is exactly my issue.Everytime I run through scheduler ,it runs successfully with 0 records change and I know there are 100s of files in content assets still in the system with no link to any pages.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i was able to get to the path to contentassets in case anyone is facing the similar issue.
Navigating to

**/EPiServer/CMS/admin/ManageContent.aspx?id=10574**

where 10574is the content Id

Here is the episerver forum post that was helpful:

https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/CMS/Thread-Container/2019/2/how-to-delete-unreferenced-content-from-the-ui/

So the url needs to be
**https://loca.abc.com/EPiServer/CMS/admin/ManageContent.aspx?id=10574**

In summary, i had to build the above url.

1- https://loca.abc.com/ can be found using isitedefinitionresolver

2- define a const string /EPiServer/CMS/admin/ManageContent.aspx?id=

3- append contend id at the end.in this case 10574

This url will give you option to either edit/manage/delete/move the item to trash.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you need, but if you want to determine an assets' folder you could look into the [ContentAssetHelper](https://world.episerver.com/csclasslibraries/cms/EPiServer.Core.ContentAssetHelper?version=11)